# Left String Function on Pandas Dataframe that Finds Character Location to Stop

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that has a column that looks like this:

```
>>> df_clean['my_column']

     my_column  
0   COMPANY1 VIDEO  
1   COMPANY2 VIDEO  
2   COMPANY1 VIDEO
```

I want to create a new column `(df_clean['my_column_trim'] = pd.DataFrame(df_raw['my_column']...` that takes all of the text, starting on the left, until the first `' '` so the result would look like:

```
>>> df_clean['my_column_trim']

     my_column_trim  
0   COMPANY1  
1   COMPANY2  
2   COMPANY1
```

I'm trying to search for the first `' '` and then do a left function until that location (pseudo-code equivalent `df_clean['final_network'].left(find(' '))`).

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split on whitespace, then `.str[0]` to get the first item of the split:

```
df_clean['my_column_trim'] = df_clean['my_column'].str.split().str[0]
```

The resulting output:

```
        my_column my_column_trim
0  COMPANY1 VIDEO       COMPANY1
1  COMPANY2 VIDEO       COMPANY2
2  COMPANY1 VIDEO       COMPANY1
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that's how split worked.